# Is there a more simple way to calculate surface integral on hemisphere?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

$S$ is the upper surface of hemisphere, $S=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z>0\}$. There is a vector field $\mathbf{F}=(u,v,w)=(\frac{x^3}{3}+z^2,x^2+y^2-\frac{z^3}{3},x^2 y+\frac{y^3}{3})$. Find the value of surface integral
$$\int_{S}(wy-vz)\ \mathrm{d}S$$
My first instinct is substitute $w$ and $v$ in and calculate it with polar coordinates. That is
\begin{equation}
\int_{S}\left(x^2y^2+\frac{y^4}{3}-(x^2+y^2)z+\frac{z^4}{3}\right)\ \mathrm{d}S
\end{equation}
It's a bit annoying but is OK to get the answer.

I noticed the surface $S$ has the normal vector $\mathbf{n}=(x,y,z)(z>0)$ at every point on $S$. So I tried to write the integral in the form:
$$\int_{S}(\frac{1}{2}xy^2-xz,\frac{1}{2}x^2 y+\frac{y^3}{3}-yz,\frac{z^3}{3})\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S=\int_{S}\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S$$
Add another surface $S_{0}=\{x^2+y^2\leq1,z=0\}$ i.e. the bottom of $S$, so $S\cup S_{0}$ is closed surface and can apply Gauss divergence theorem on it.
$$=\int_{V}\text{div}\mathrm{G}\ \mathrm{d}V$$

The question I have is, the $u$ seems no use with the question, can we have a more simple way to get the result without huge calculations?

Comment: The integrand in \begin{equation}
\int_{S}\left(x^2y^2+\frac{y^4}{3}-(x^2+y^2)z+\frac{z^4}{3}\right)\ \mathrm{d}S
\end{equation}
looks correct. So does the normal vector $\mathbf{n}\,.$ There are various ways to find a $\mathbf{G}$ that leads to that integrand when dotted with $\mathbf{n}$ but the goal should be to find a $\mathbf{G}$ that is divergence free. Then we could find a $\mathbf{H}$ whose curl is $\mathbf{G}$ and apply Stokes' theorem. Completing the surface to be the unit sphere and using Gauss' theorem won't help because we are not interested in the total surface integral.

Comment: Having said that: I tried to find a divergcence free $\mathbf{G}$ without success. You may end up going to spherical polar coordinates and calculate four terms $\int_Sx^2y^2\,dS$ (and so on) individually. Quite a boring and almost useless exercise.

Comment: Just an observation, it seems like you are trying to calculate the component along $\hat x$ of $\int_S\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{r}dS$

Comment: @Andrei However Stokes's formula cannot be used here which is a pity.